# Permissions Required for GIT-TF?

Tags: git-tf

I am the admin for my company's TFS2012 server. I have gotten GIT-TF working for myself, however the other developers at my company are having permission problems. They have access to the project in question as a contributor, but performing a clone of the project is yielding permission problems. Below is a snapshot of the cmd and error:

```
git-tf clone <servername> <projectname>
Connecting to TFS...
Username: <username>
Password: 
Password: 
Password: 
git-tf: Access denied connecting to TFS server <servername> <authenticating as <username>>
```

When I perform the same command, it doesn't ask for my username and password, presumably because I am logged into Windows under a user with permission.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Are they connecting from a non-domain joined machine? If so, are they using the following format for username: _<domain>\<username>_?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help me either. I had our IT make a test user for me, logged him into a VM and I had no problems, only gave him "contributor" access to the project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you make sure to include the collection name in the url passed to the git-tf command? My company had problems exactly like you describe and that was the fix.

```
This: git-tf clone http://<server>:<port>/tfs/<collection name> $/<project name>
Not this: git-tf clone http://<server>:<port>/tfs/ $/<project name>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if project is on `dev.azure.com\[company]\[division]\$/[division]` what is the server, the port and the collection name? there is any place on Visual Studio or on Azure Devops where we can see that information?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Maybe they configured a proxy with the HTTP_PROXY environment variable, and your TFS server is local and the proxy should not be used to access it. It gave me the same symptom.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Solution was: 
1. Use https://github.com/new/import instead as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331930/how-to-import-a-project-from-visual-studio-online-to-github). 
2. Create and pass personal access token as described [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/overview).

Comment: I needed personal access token in order to access TFS server using git-tf on Mac. It didn't work with my regular password.