# How to import a project from Visual Studio Online to GitHub?

Tags: github, azure-devops

I have a couple project in Visual Studio Online (VSO), which I would like to move to my GitHub account. In VSO all projects are not publicly-readable. You must be authenticated using Microsoft Account (MA).

I tried to use the GitHub Importer (https://import.github.com/new) to do that. The importer asked me for read-only credentials to reach out to my project. Unfortunately, it cannot go through authentication event though I provide my MA credentials.

Is there anybody know how to import a project from Visual Studio Online to GitHub? Is it even possible?

Comment: Is importing a Visual Studio project really any different from, say, a J2EE project or something in iOS?

Comment: VSO is TFS-as-a-Service. My projects are stored in Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC), which can handle whatever language.

Answer (score 10):

Okay. I figured it out.  You must enable the alternate authentication credentials as described in the following article.  After that the importer starts doing its job:

https://web.archive.org/web/20161204015026/https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/overview

Comment: This worked exactly as described. My first thought was maybe to use http over https. That was a false positive, as it got through auth but failed to find my projects. Using https and these alternate credentials I was able to import my project perfectly.

Comment: Link is dead... got a new one?

Comment: @CiaranGallagher - not a perfect match, but maybe this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qs7SRnqc_M) at about 1:43 might help?

Answer (score 1):

If you're importing from Azure DevOps, don't use your account credentials while importing. Instead goto Azure Repos, select your repo which you are importing, then click on **Clone** and then click on **Generate Credentials** and then use those credentials in GitHub importer.

Comment: those generate credentials did not work for me.  Github just kept prompting for credentials

Answer (score 0):

> My projects are stored in Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC), which can handle whatever language.

Then, starting Apr. 2023, this is soon (Oct. 2023) no longer possible:

> ### [Deprecation: Importing non-Git repositories with GitHub Importer](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-04-17-deprecation-importing-non-git-repositories-with-github-importer) (Apr. 2023)
>
> [GitHub Importer](https://docs.github.com/en/migrations/importing-source-code/using-github-importer/about-github-importer) allows you to import repositories from other code hosting platforms to GitHub.com using a [UI](https://github.com/new/import) or [REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/migrations/source-imports?apiVersion=2022-11-28#about-source-imports).
>
> Today, GitHub Importer supports Git, Mercurial, Subversion and Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) repositories.
>
> From October 17, 2023, we will **no longer support importing Mercurial, Subversion and Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) repositories**.
>
> We're ending support for this functionality due to extremely low levels of usage.
>
> Even without GitHub Importer, moving from these alternative version control systems to Git is simple thanks to fantastic open source tools – for more details, read our Docs article, ["Using the command line to import source code"](https://docs.github.com/migrations/importing-source-code/using-the-command-line-to-import-source-code).