# Please suggest another fastest way for Migrating SVN repository to GIT respository

Tags: ruby, git, svn, git-svn, svn2git

Downloaded the `Ruby` Installer for Windows and installed the latest version with Add `Ruby` executable to your path.

Installed `svn2git`.

Start menu ->All programs -> Ruby -> Start command prompt with ruby
Then type `“gem install svn2git”` and enter.

Migrate subversion repository

In `Ruby` command prompt gone to the directory where the files to be migrated

Then used the below command

> `svn2git http://[domain name]/svn/ [repository root]`

It is taking around 2 days to migrate 20K commits into GIT and in SVN we have around 65K commits.

Please let me know is there any other fastest way to migrate the SVN repository to GIT repository.

Comment: Try [subgit](http://www.subgit.com).

Comment: Sure I hope it will help me and let you know the status too.
Thanks @axiac for such a fast reply.

Comment: You could try my [Git Extensions](https://github.com/gburghardt/Git-Extensions) collection of shell scripts. It provides a utility for importing SVN repositories. I set this up as a cron job that cycled through the SVN commits in batches of 1,000. It took all weekend, but it was a pretty stable way to convert the repo over without exposing company code to an outside source.

Comment: @axiac sorry I could not see any difference between `svn2git` and `subgit` both are slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the github importer:

https://help.github.com/articles/importing-from-subversion/

I don't have any information on speed though.

Comment: very much appreciated ... if I get an example for importing a SVN repositoy to GIT [in this](https://import.github.com/new). I found an issue like URL is not supported while checking the URL in the [import site](https://import.github.com/new).

Comment: Warning: [Support for SVN migration will soon be dropped (Oct. 2023)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76038365/6309)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what does `svn2git` do, but with the standard `git-svn` we noticed substantial slowness on the windows machines, especially annoying when doing the initial import indeed. There were two ways to solve it: performing the import on macos/linux machine and then simply copying the resulting repo onto the windows workstation or partial import (`git svn fetch -R <recent revision>`).

Comment: ohh.. I have no Linux servers servers with me.